# ListView , Is there a way to increase the height?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I don't know why when I put constraints on the text views and such it won't come out the exact position I want it to be, I'm thinking it may be the listview height issue that is pushing everything together

**The image below is the problem showing:**

[image]

**This is my adapter:**

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Put the food_list_layout in the convertView
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.preorder_list_layout_orders,null);
        }
```

**this is my XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orderID"
        android:layout_width="319dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"

        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Transaction ID"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.25"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.011" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.066"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.074"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orderFoodName"
        android:layout_width="168dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Food Name"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.607"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.091" />

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="59dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Quantity: "
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.146" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orderQuantity"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Quantity"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.698"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.145" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orderAN"
        android:layout_width="371dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"

        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="addnotes"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.791"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.282" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="124dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Collection Timing:"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.07"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/orderAN"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.015" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orderCT2"
        android:layout_width="124dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Collection Timing"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/orderAN"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.015" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Additional Notes: "
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.068"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.237" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using fixed size for your views and this is making your screen non-responsive .

If you want to achieve a responsive layout don't use fixed size, You can use `ConstraintLayout` but with `android:layout_width="0dp"` , `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` attribute and some [Guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html).

**Here is an example for your wanted layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layoutDirection="ltr"
  android:orientation="vertical">



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/orderID"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"

    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Transaction ID"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.011" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/orderID"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/orderID"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/orderFoodName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Food Name"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.607"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2" />

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Quantity: "
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/orderFoodName"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/orderFoodName"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.146" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/orderQuantity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Quantity"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.145" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/orderAN"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="addnotes"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/orderID"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Collection Timing:"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/orderID"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/orderAN"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.015" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/orderCT2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Collection Timing"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.015" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Additional Notes: "
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/orderAN"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/orderID"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="385dp"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="144dp" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="392dp"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**It will look like this:**

[image]

Comment: Did you just copy-paste it? because you will need to change  `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout ` to `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`

Comment: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #152: Binary XML file line #152: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #152: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.owner-yaBDEkayrb8TUNUcxFBjfQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.owner-yaBDEkayrb8TUNUcxFBjfQ==/lib/x86,

Comment: Also, replace `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline` with `android.support.constraint.Guideline`

Comment: Isn't the problem with my code is due to the listview height ? isn't it possible to increase the listview height of each row ?

Comment: You can change you constraint layout to 500 dp if you would like to.but it wont look the same on every device.In mu opinion its better to create 1 layout for all devices is possible

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orderID"
        android:layout_width="319dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:text="Transaction ID"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_image_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/orderQuantity"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/orderFoodName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/orderID" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orderFoodName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="97dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:text="Food Name"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/orderQuantity"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/orderID" />

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="176dp"
        android:text="Quantity: "
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/orderQuantity"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/orderQuantity"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orderQuantity"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="106dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:text="Quantity"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orderAN"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:text="addnotes"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="367dp"
        android:text="Collection Timing:"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/orderCT2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/orderAN" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orderCT2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="128dp"
        android:text="Collection Timing"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView6" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:text="Additional Notes: "
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/orderAN"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/orderAN"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/orderQuantity" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hey John Joe, your provided code will not be responsive for every screen size and let me explain why:
You are using fixed sizes a lot, for example `android:layout_marginEnd="128dp`.Those are very large sizes in dp - check my answer below, I believe it can help you better understand the power of ConstraintLayout

Comment: In addition,  my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55539919/8274756) is more detailed if you want do read more about responsive layout.